# Combining values from two arrays

Tags: javascript, css, arrays

I am working on an Express app and have an issue trying to match up the values of two arrays

I have a user-entered string which which come through to me from a form (e.g.`let analyseStory = req.body.storyText`).  This string contains line breaks as `\r\n\`.

An example of string is

```
In the mens reserve race, Cambridges Goldie were beaten by Oxfords 
Isis, their seventh consecutive defeat. \r\n\r\nIn the womens reserve 
race, Cambridges Blondie defeated Oxfords Osiris
```

However before I print this to the browser the string is run through a text analysis library called pos e.g.
`const tagger = new pos.Tagger();
res.locals.taggedWords =  tagger.tag(analyseStory);`

This returns to me an array of words in the string and their grammatical type

```
[ [ 'In', 'Noun, sing. or mass' ],
  [ 'the', 'Determiner' ],
  [ 'mens', 'Noun, plural' ],
  [ 'reserve', 'Noun, sing. or mass' ],
  [ 'race', 'Noun, sing. or mass' ],
  [ ',', 'Comma' ],
  [ 'Cambridges', 'Noun, plural' ],
  [ 'Goldie', 'Proper noun, sing.' ],
  [ 'were', 'verb, past tense' ],
  [ 'beaten', 'verb, past part' ],
  [ 'by', 'Preposition' ],
  [ 'Oxfords', 'Noun, plural' ],
....
]
```

Currently when I print this user-entered text to the screen I loop through the array and print out the key and then wrap that in a class containing the value.  This gives a result like:

`<span class="noun-sing-or-mass">In</span>
<span class="determiner">the</span>
<span class="noun-plural">mens</span>`

so that I can style them.

This all works fine but the problem is that I lose my line breaks in the process.  I'm really not sure how to solve this problem but I was thinking that perhaps I could do this on the client side if I break the initial string I get (`analyseStory`) into an array (where commas, full stops are array items as they are in the above) and then apply the grammatical type supplied in `res.locals.taggedWords` to the array generated from  `analyseStory` string.  However I'm not sure how to do this or even if it is the right solution to the problem.

FWIW if I print `analyseStory` to the screen without pushng it through text analysis I handle line breaks by wrapping the string in `<span style="white-space: pre-line">User entered string</span>` rather than converting to `<br />`.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: if you need line break, use `<p>` instead `<span>` for certain words. or for specific class like $('span.noun-sing-or-mass'), wrap them with `<p>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution uses ES6 [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), and [`String.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with a RegExp to find all words in the analysis, and replace them with a span that has the relevant class name.

You can see in the demo that it preserves the line breaks. Inspect the elements to see the spans with the classes.

```js
const str = 'In the mens reserve race, Cambridges Goldie were beaten by Oxfords  Isis, their seventh consecutive defeat. \r\n\r\nIn the womens reserve race, Cambridges Blondie defeated Oxfords Osiris';

const analyzed = [["In","Noun, sing. or mass"],["the","Determiner"],["mens","Noun, plural"],["reserve","Noun, sing. or mass"],["race","Noun, sing. or mass"],[",","Comma"],["Cambridges","Noun, plural"],["Goldie","Proper noun, sing."],["were","verb, past tense"],["beaten","verb, past part"],["by","Preposition"],["Oxfords","Noun, plural"]];

// create Map from the analyzed array. Use Array.map() to change all keys to lower case, and prepare the class name
const analyzedMap = new Map(analyzed.map(([k, v]) => 
  [k.toLowerCase(), v.trim().toLowerCase().replace(/\W+/g, '-')]));

// search for a sequence word characters or special characters such as comman and period
const result = str.replace(/(:?\w+|,|.)/gi, (m) => {
  // get the class name from the Map
  const className = analyzedMap.get(m.toLowerCase());
  
  // if there is a class name return the word/character wrapped with a span
  if(className) return `<span class="${className}">${m}</span>`;
  
  // return the word
  return m;
});

demo.innerHTML = result;
```

```css
#demo {
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<span>` is not a block level element. By default it will not line break. You need to either make it block level with css or wrap your text in something that is block level like a `<p>` tag.

**CSS To Make Block**

```
span { display: block; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pre-process text before analyzing text and replace line breaks with some special characters. Something like the following:

```js
const story_with_br = analyseStory.replace(/\n/g, "__br__");
const tagger = new pos.Tagger();
res.locals.taggedWords =  tagger.tag(story_with_br);
```

Hopefully, taggedWords array will contain `"__br__"` and if it does then while rendering you can add line breaks instead of `"__br__"`

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is :

**Option 1**

Edit the library you're using so that it doesn't ignore your `\r\n`

**Option 2**

Define a complex key which will define the newlines :

```
const newlinesKey = 'yourkeyvalue';
```

Then you replace all newlines by your newlinesKey :

```
analyseStory.replace(/\r\n/g, newlinesKey);
```

And after that you can call the text analysis library :

```
const tagger = new pos.Tagger();
res.locals.taggedWords =  tagger.tag(analyseStory);
```

Like this you would be able to detect when you have to put a new line if the tagger doesn't ignore the keyValue.